# Why my addClass is not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The code link is here

http://jsfiddle.net/sagesony/ryG6Z/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").draggable({ revert:"invalid" });
    $("#box2").draggable({ revert:"invalid" });
    $("#target").droppable({ 
        accept: "#box2",
        drop: function(event,ui) {
        accept: "#box2",
            $("#target").addClass("changecolor"); }

    });
 });
```

My addClass is not working when I move the #box2 over the #target.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working in your fiddle

Comment: I am not able to see it. The border color is supposed to change or if I add the background-color to the class.......it doesn't change.

Comment: your setting it to white with an already white background, so you cant see it.  try setting it to red or something if you want to see it or set a background color

Answer (score 1):

**You have a few problems here:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").draggable({ revert:"invalid" });
    $("#box2").draggable({ revert:"invalid" });
    $("#target").droppable({ 
        accept: "#box2",
        drop: function(event,ui) {
            //accept: "#box2",  <- This is wrong and won't run  
            $(event.target).addClass("changecolor"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Remove the `accept: "#box2",`
You can get the target by using `$(event.target)` or `$(this)`

**CSS problem:**
The way CSS works, IDs has higher priority than Classes, therefor when you add the `changecolor`class, it won't override the CSS.

You can fix this by changing this:

```
.changecolor{
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

to

```
#target.changecolor{
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

**[Here is a JSFiddle where it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ryG6Z/3/)**

Comment: @user3235729 You should NOT use `!important`. If you need to use `!important` that usuablly means that there is something fundementally wrong with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `important` rule to your style,because there are another styles defined for border of same 
div. To give the highest priority to your `changeColor` class you should use !important rule.

```
.changecolor{
    border: 2px solid white !important;

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/ryG6Z/2/)

Comment: Using the `!important` notation is not recommended. Because it just hides the real issue. Generally !important should only be used if you are giving up.

Comment: Thanks...never knew about the !important. Now it is perfectly working.

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen you are totaly right but what if the user want to use the class with other divs that has different IDs.

Comment: @sMr `changecolor` is not really descriptive, and even if he called it `border-white` it would still be bad design. Using `!important` is a quickfix, that will bite him in the ass later on, if he wants to add more classes etc. Re-usability is better used in bigger concepts, and using `!important` in such a simple design, means something is fundamentally wrong with it.